# C: How to open a file ending with a particular extension

Tags: c

I need to create a program that is supposed to read a file with a ".deck" extension. That is, the program argument should be `-d1 <name>.deck` . The `-d1` string must always be written and the `.deck`  extension is mandatory, the `<name>` can be any given string with any given length. The `.deck` file is basically a text file with a poker card deck.
Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is likely people are going to down vote you because you didn't included any code you have written so far. Maybe include some? Or in case you got none, maybe include your thoughts on solving this problem.

Comment: `fopen(argv[n+1], "r")` might do the trick when "-d1" is at `argv[n]`.

Comment: You can test the validity of the filename using a combination of `strlen` and `strcmp`: `size_t fnlen = strlen(filename);` `if (fnlen < 6 || strcmp(&filename[fnlen - 5], ".deck") != 0) {` `/* filename invalid */` `} else {` `/* filename valid */` `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for.

Currently the following programs loops over all of the command line arguments and searches for a `-d1` flag. When found, it ensures the next argument exists, that it is a string with a .deck extension before it tries to open it.

Note this program won't handle multiple files.
You will need to implement some sort of linked list or array to store multiple `fds` or strings.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static const char *FLAG = "-d1";
static const char *EXTENSION = ".deck";

int is_deck_file(char const *string)
{
    int length = strlen(string);

    if (length < 6)
        return 0;
    if (strcmp(string + (length - 5), EXTENSION) == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int fd = -2;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], FLAG) == 0) {
            if (i + 1 < argc && is_deck_file(argv[i + 1])) {
                i++;
                fd = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
            } else {
                dprintf(2, "Error: %s flag must be followed by a filepath.\n", FLAG);
            }
        }
    }
    if (fd == -2)
        dprintf(2, "No file was provided.\n");
    else if (fd == -1)
        dprintf(2, "Unable to open file.\n");
    else
        dprintf(1, "File provided, with right extension!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you are going to do is, firstly extract the entire `"-d1 *"` string out of the `**argv` variable. To do this just loop around `**argv` and check if its first four characters are `"-d1 "` or not. After that, copy it to a string, say `s`, and delete all the empty space at the end of `s`. To do that, use a while loop. Finally check if the last 5 characters in `s` are `".deck"` or not.

(Pseudocode)

```
target="-d1 ";
loop i from 0 to argc-1{
    flag=true;
    loop j from 0 to 3{
        if (argv[i][j]!=target[j]){
            flag=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag){
        break;
    }
}
if (!flag){
    /* ERROR - NO "-d1" ARGUMENT */
}
str=copy(argv[i]);
len=length(str)-1;
while (len>0)&&(str[len]==' '){
    len--;
}
if (len<6){
    /* ERROR - THE STRING IS CERTAINLY INVALID */
}
flag=true;
target="kced."; /* reverse of ".deck" */
loop i from 0 to 4{
    if (str[len-i]!=target[i]){
         flag=false;
    }
}
if (!flag){
    /* ERROR - FILENAME IS INVALID */
}
/* proceed */
```